# Center item from fragment when parent view doesn't fill whole Screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm having some troubles with my XML design. I have added a Viewpager to my application, together with a Toolbar in top of the application. So, my problem is that when I try to gravity center the items from my fragments which belong to my Viewpager, the will be set in the midle of the Viewpager, ignoring the Toolbar height.

So, I want to ask if is possible to center items from a view or fragment in the middle of the screen when their parent view doesn't fill the entire screen.

My activity XML is this one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"></include>

<com.example.android.ui.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/module_selector_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/view_pager_top"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_below="@id/module_selector_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The items which I want to center are inside the Fragments that I add dynamically to the Viewpager with a FragmentAdapter.

Right now my apps looks like, I just want to center in the whole Screen the timer Text & the CircleProgressBar, Right now they are align in the midle of the viewpager:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your screenshot what you want?

Comment: added photo and a bit more of definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I moved my layouts one above another to get the result that I wanted!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/fragment_background"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/countdownLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_layout">

    <com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.CircleProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/progressbar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/progressbar_size"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/timer_name_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/medium_light_hms"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timerText" />


    <com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.HmsView
        android:id="@+id/timerText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.ZeroTopPaddingTextView
            android:id="@+id/hours_ones"
            style="@style/medium_light_hms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours_label"
            style="@style/fragment_label"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/hms_picker_hours_label"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.ZeroTopPaddingTextView
            android:id="@+id/minutes_tens"
            style="@style/medium_light_hms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.ZeroTopPaddingTextView
            android:id="@+id/minutes_ones"
            style="@style/medium_light_hms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minutes_label"
            style="@style/fragment_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/hms_picker_minutes_label" />

        <com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.ZeroTopPaddingTextView
            android:id="@+id/seconds_tens"
            style="@style/medium_light_hms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.ZeroTopPaddingTextView
            android:id="@+id/seconds_ones"
            style="@style/medium_light_hms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seconds_label"
            style="@style/fragment_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/hms_picker_seconds_label" />
    </com.example.android.voicetimer.ui.HmsView>
</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/delete_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/delete_button_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/icon_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black"
        android:tint="@color/icon_tint" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is about the fragment, not the Viewpager. Can you paste the layout of the fragment?

From the image, what I would do is a Vertical Linear Layout with two children, the first one for the circle and the other one for the buttons.

Then, you can use layout_weight to control where do the children begin and end.

More information about layout_weight:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

I'm sorry but I don't have the layout editor right now.